global header and footer not showing for custom blog listing template on hubspot
I am new to hubspot. I created a theme and inside it I created "blog-index.html. I am able to see the posts inside the blog listing template but it doesn't show me the header and footer. on the homepage I am able to see it but not in the blogs page. I tried importing header.html from a theme but I am not sure if it is the template it is the same also the css is not loading. I am new so I don't have any idea how to do this.
<!--
  templateType: blog_listing
  isAvailableForNewContent: true
  enableDomainStylesheets: true
  label: Boilerplate - blog listing
  screenshotPath: ../images/template-previews/blog-index.png
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Blog Listing</title>
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
    body {
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
    }

   .filter-buttons {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


  </style>
  
</head>
<body> 
   {% block header %}
        {% global_partial path="SmartStart/templates/partials/header.html" %}
      {% endblock header %}
  <div class="filter-buttons"> 
    <a  
      href="/blog"  
      class="{% if request.path == '/blog' or request.path == '/blog/' %}active{% endif %}"> 
      All
    </a> 
         
    {% set my_topics = blog_topics('default', 250) %} 
    {% for item in my_topics %} 
    <a  
      href="{{ blog_tag_url(group.id, item.slug) }}"  
      class="{% if '/blog/tag/' + item.slug in request.path %}active{% endif %}"> 
      {{ item.name }} 
    </a> 
    {% endfor %} 
  </div> 

  <div class="blog-listing"> 
    <div class="blog-listing-container"> 
      {# Set pagination variables #}
      {% set posts_per_page = 6 %}
      {% set total_posts = contents|length %}
      {% set total_pages = (total_posts / posts_per_page)|round(0, 'ceil')|int %}
      {% set current_page = request.query_dict.page|default('1')|int %}
      {% set start_index = (current_page - 1) * posts_per_page %}
      {% set end_index = start_index + posts_per_page %}

      {# Display paginated posts #}
      {% for content in contents[start_index:end_index] %} 
      <div class="card"> 
        <img src="{{ content.featured_image }}" alt="{{ content.name }}"> 
        <div class="card-body"> 
          <div class="blog-tags"> 
            {% if content.tag_list %} 
            <div> 
              {% for tag in content.tag_list %} 
              <a class="tags" href="/blog/tag/{{ tag.slug }}">{{ tag.name }}</a>{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %} 
              {% endfor %} 
            </div> 
            {% endif %} 
          </div> 
          <h2 class="title"><a href="{{ content.absolute_url }}">{{ content.name }}</a></h2> 
          <p class="description">{{ content.post_summary|truncate(98, true) }}</p> 
        </div> 
      </div> 
      {% endfor %} 
    </div>

    {# Pagination navigation #}
    {% if total_pages > 1 %}
    <div class="pagination">
      {# Previous page link #}
      <a href="?page={{ current_page - 1 }}" 
         class="{% if current_page == 1 %}disabled{% endif %}">
        Previous
      </a>

      {# Page numbers #}
      {% for page in range(1, total_pages + 1) %}
        <a href="?page={{ page }}"
           class="{% if page == current_page %}active{% endif %}">
          {{ page }}
        </a>
      {% endfor %}

      {# Next page link #}
      <a href="?page={{ current_page + 1 }}"
         class="{% if current_page == total_pages %}disabled{% endif %}">
        Next
      </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div> 
  
   {% block footer %}
        {% global_partial path="SmartStart/templates/partials/footer.html" %}
      {% endblock footer %}
</body> 
</html>


